# How import module gi in python 2.7 on windows 10

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk

I have problem while I importing GTK packages after I wrote this code :

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

this is result :

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/83ahmad/PycharmProjects/GTK/1-simple.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/83ahmad/PycharmProjects/GTK/1-simple.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gi
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

---

Please help me in this problem ???